# Dynamically update topics list for spark kafka consumer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Is it possible to dynamically update topics list in spark-kafka consumer?

I have a Spark Streaming application which uses spark-kafka consumer.
Say initially I have spark-kakfa consumer listening for topics: ["test"] and after a while my topics list got updated to ["test","testNew"]. now is there a way to update spark-kafka consumer topics list and ask spark-kafka consumer to consume data for updated list of topics without stopping sparkStreaming application or sparkStreaming context

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to dynamically update topics list in spark-kafka consumer

No. Both the receiver and receiverless approaches are fixed once you initialize the kafka stream using `KafkaUtils`. There is no way for you to pass new topics as you go as the DAG is fixed.

If you want to read dynamically, perhaps consider a batch k
job which is scheduled iteratively and can read the topics dynamically and creating an `RDD` out of that.

An additional solution would be to use a technology that gives you kore flexibility over the consumption, such as Akka Streams.

Answer (score 0):

As Yuval said, it isn't possible but there might be a work around if you know what the structure/format of data you are dealing with from Kafka.

For example,

- If your streaming application is listening to topics ["test","testNew"]
- Downl the line you want to add a new topic named [test4], as a work around, you can simply add a unique key to the that is contained in it and pass it to the existing topics.
- Design your streaming application in such a way to recognize/filter the data based on the key you added to that test2 data

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread based approach
1. define the Cache using any data structure which contains list of topics
2. way to add element in this cache
3. You have to class A and B where B has all the spark related logic
4 Class A is long running job and from  A you are calling B , whenever there is  new topic you just spawning  new thread with B

Comment: I am currently using a similar approach, but this has many complications like need to stop streaming context gracefully every time I need to update the topics list. this being a  async process, is unpredictable in terms of time taken to stop. all this while I will not be able to process the stream of data coming in. streaming context needs to stop, start and resume the computation.

Comment: @rohith-yeravothula did you find any alternative solution, I can think only using Akka stream with actor system. I tried SubscribePattern but that is only kind of filter topic during startup not to add topic during DAG and stream is scheduled.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest trying [ConsumerStrategies.SubscribePattern](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-streaming/spark-streaming-kafka-ConsumerStrategy.adoc#SubscribePattern) from the latest [Spark-Kafka integration (0.10)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html) API version.

That would look like:

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
mySparkStreamingContext,
PreferConsistent,
SubscribePattern("test.*".r.pattern, myKafkaParamsMap))
```

Comment: I tried the same, it does not pick topic dynamically means yes when you start the stream it will use regex to match all topics(just like filters) and create stream for those. We are looking for a solution where while stream is already running , can I add new topic dynamically. Looks like it is not possible because the way spark cluster works it can reschedule jobs and stream DAG.